# What is wrong with my reselect function ? I dont get an output

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux, reselect

I want to use reselect. I want to get my shopping cart by the ids.

reselect.ts

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";
import { RootState } from "../store";

export const shoppingCarts = (state: RootState) => state.ShoppingCart;

export const getCartById = (state: any, id: string) => createSelector(
  shoppingCarts,
  state => state.find(cart => cart.product?.id === id)
);
```

Index.tsx

```
  const { product_id } = props;
  const shoppingCart = useSelector(state => getCartById(state, product_id));

  console.log(shoppingCart);
```

console log output

```
[Function memoized]
```

how can I get the output of my function (or the json value) ?

if I make this

```
shoppingCart()
```

then I get this

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.ShoppingCart')
```

Comment: Reselect provides a function, which allows you to cache items since the state might not be the same instance. Typically, you leverage [`redux` connect](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#defining-mapstatetoprops) and pass that into your component props. You can test it with something local though like `shoppingCart(exampleState)`. However, your example does not actually provide `packet_id` so I'm not sure where that is coming from unless you provide more context. Reselect docs provide some good examples though: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#basic-usage

Comment: I want to find all products with ids in my shoping cart, so  why I have to say shoppingCart(exampleState) ? I dont have a exampleState because I want to find the products in my shopping cart so my shoppingCart is my state

Answer (score 0):

Because `getCartById` is a selector factory function, NOT a selector. That's why you got `[Function memoized]` log when you called it inside `useSelector`.

Take a look at the doc [How do I create a selector that takes an argument?](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument).

> provide input selectors that extract the arguments and forward them to the output selector for calculation

E.g.

```
const selectItemsByCategory = createSelector(
  [
    // Usual first input - extract value from `state`
    state => state.items,
    // Take the second arg, `category`, and forward to the output selector
    (state, category) => category
  ],
  // Output selector gets (`items, category)` as args
  (items, category) => items.filter(item => item.category === category)
)
```

So, It should be:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

export const shoppingCarts = (state) => state.carts;

export const getCartById = createSelector([shoppingCarts, (_, productId: string) => productId], (carts, productId) =>
  carts.find((cart) => cart.product?.id === productId),
);
```

Test

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { getCartById } from '.';

describe('72135522', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const product_id = '1';
    function TestComp() {
      const cart = useSelector((state) => getCartById(state, product_id));
      console.log(cart);
      return null;
    }
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      carts: (state = [{ product: { id: '1' } }, { product: { id: '2' } }]) => state,
    });
    const store = createStore(rootReducer);
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TestComp />
      </Provider>,
    );
  });
});
```

The logs:

```sh
 console.log
    { product: { id: '1' } }
```